Does every triangle satisfy $a+b-c \ge R\left(\frac{d}{R}\right)^{\pi}$ where $d$ is the smallest difference between any two sides?
Definition: Let $d$ be the smallest positive difference between the length of any two sides of a triangle. WLOG, if $a \le b \le c$ be the sides of a triangle then, $d = \min(b-a,c-b)$.
Let $R$ be the circumradius of the triangle. Experimental evidence show that here is a constant $\alpha \approx 3.131753$ such that for all $x \ge \alpha$
$$
a+b-c \ge R\left(\frac{d}{R}\right)^{x}.
$$
Question: Can this be proved and what is the value of this constant $\alpha$?
It is intersting to note the proximity of the estimated value of $\alpha$ to $\pi$ although this could be a coincidence.

There must be a formula for $R$ depending on $a,b,c$. Did you try to use that somehow ?

From the final formula for $r$ from Circumcircle#Higher dimensions in wikipedia and applying the law of cosines and the relation between the dot product and the interior angle, we get $$R = \frac{abc}{\sqrt{4a^2b^2 - (a^2+b^2 - c^2)^2}}$$

Later on, under Other properties, the same article gives the formulas (translating diameter into radius): $$R = \frac{abc}{4A} = \frac{abc}{4\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}}$$ where $A$ is the area of the triangle and $s = \frac{a+b+c}2$ is the semiperimeter.
